# Displaying non-formatted text in HTML and adding colors

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text file (e.g. a Gutenberg book) I want to display in an HTML page dynamically. I know how to load the file using Javascript, but I'm not sure how to properly display it. Simple document.write-ing it is not good since it destroyes line breaks (and maybe other things?).

I can put the text inside TextArea and then it'll look fine, but I want one more thing: To be able to color specific letters in the text in different colors (e.g. color the fifth "h" in blue and the seventh "h" in red). I don't think TextArea can do it; I thought simply to wrap the letter by some div and use CSS.

So, how do I transform the text from the file to something that is HTML-friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PRE tag for this, I have created a jsFiddle with an example - http://jsfiddle.net/X68Af/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap` in CSS. If you use `<pre>` in HTML instead, note that it by default sets font to monospace, which is generally bad for any normal text.

However, if line breaks are really relevant, you should replace them by `<br>` or, as the case may be, by `<p>`. In most legacy texts, line breaks are coincidental, not essential. If they are essential, they probably indicate paragraph break (`<p>`), logically speaking.